# Calculating Amazon MWS Signature using Java / Filemaker

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, base64, digital-signature, hmac

We've been trying to calculate the Amazon Signature for the past few days using the Java code provided on Amazon's site.

I'm not a seasoned Java developer, but we've managed to use the basis of their code found at http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/dev_guide/DG_ClientLibraries.html#DG_OwnClientLibrary__Signatures to generate a signature but we keep getting a "signature doesn't match" error that we're running into a wall debugging. Here is our current Java code with account specific information omitted:

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SignatureException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Date;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.TimeZone;
import java.util.Date;

public class Main {
    private static final String CHARACTER_ENCODING = "UTF-8";
    final static String ALGORITHM = "HmacSHA256";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // Change this secret key to yours
        String secretKey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"; // This secret key does have a forward slash in it (3rd to last character), would that adversely affect anything?

        // Use the endpoint for your marketplace
        String serviceUrl = "https://mws.amazonservices.com/Orders/2011-01-01";

        // Create set of parameters needed and store in a map
        HashMap<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String,String>();

        // Add required parameters. Change these as needed.
        parameters.put("AWSAccessKeyId", urlEncode("XXXXXXXXXXX"));
        parameters.put("Action", urlEncode("ListOrders"));
        parameters.put("MarketplaceId.Id.1", urlEncode("ATVPDKIKX0DER"));
        parameters.put("Merchant", urlEncode("ALZYDHGPLQNLD"));
        parameters.put("OrderStatus.Status.1", urlEncode("PartiallyShipped"));
        parameters.put("OrderStatus.Status.2", urlEncode("Unshipped"));
        parameters.put("SignatureMethod", urlEncode(ALGORITHM));
        parameters.put("SignatureVersion", urlEncode("2"));
        parameters.put("Timestamp", urlEncode("2014-01-29T22:11:00Z"));
        parameters.put("Version", urlEncode("2011-01-01"));
        //parameters.put("SubmittedFromDate", urlEncode("2014-01-28T15:05:00Z"));

        // Format the parameters as they will appear in final format
        // (without the signature parameter)
        String formattedParameters = calculateStringToSignV2(parameters, serviceUrl);
        //System.out.println(formattedParameters);

        String signature = sign(formattedParameters, secretKey);
        System.out.println(urlEncode(signature));

        // Add signature to the parameters and display final results
        parameters.put("Signature", urlEncode(signature));
        System.out.println(calculateStringToSignV2(parameters, serviceUrl));

        // TEST AREA
        // Signiture sig = new Signiture();
        // String HMAC = sig.calculateRFC2104HMAC(parameters, secretKey);
        // TEST AREA
    }

    /* If Signature Version is 2, string to sign is based on following:
    *
    *    1. The HTTP Request Method followed by an ASCII newline (%0A)
    *
    *    2. The HTTP Host header in the form of lowercase host,
    *       followed by an ASCII newline.
    *
    *    3. The URL encoded HTTP absolute path component of the URI
    *       (up to but not including the query string parameters);
    *       if this is empty use a forward '/'. This parameter is followed
    *       by an ASCII newline.
    *
    *    4. The concatenation of all query string components (names and
    *       values) as UTF-8 characters which are URL encoded as per RFC
    *       3986 (hex characters MUST be uppercase), sorted using
    *       lexicographic byte ordering. Parameter names are separated from
    *       their values by the '=' character (ASCII character 61), even if
    *       the value is empty. Pairs of parameter and values are separated
    *       by the '&' character (ASCII code 38).
    *
    */
    private static String calculateStringToSignV2(Map<String, String> parameters, String serviceUrl)
            throws SignatureException, URISyntaxException {
        // Sort the parameters alphabetically by storing
        // in TreeMap structure
        Map<String, String> sorted = new TreeMap<String, String>();
        sorted.putAll(parameters);

        // Set endpoint value
        URI endpoint = new URI(serviceUrl.toLowerCase());

        // Create flattened (String) representation
        StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
        /*data.append("POST\n");
        data.append(endpoint.getHost());
        data.append("\n/");
        data.append("\n");*/

        Iterator<Entry<String, String>> pairs = sorted.entrySet().iterator();

        while (pairs.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<String, String> pair = pairs.next();
            if (pair.getValue() != null) {
                data.append( pair.getKey() + "=" + pair.getValue());
            }
            else {
                data.append( pair.getKey() + "=");
            }

            // Delimit parameters with ampersand (&)
            if (pairs.hasNext()) {
                data.append( "&");
            }
        }

        return data.toString();
    }

    /*
     * Sign the text with the given secret key and convert to base64
     */
    private static String sign(String data, String secretKey)
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException,
                   IllegalStateException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
        //System.out.println(mac);//
        mac.init(new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getBytes(CHARACTER_ENCODING), ALGORITHM));
        //System.out.println(mac);//
        byte[] signature = mac.doFinal(data.getBytes(CHARACTER_ENCODING));
        //System.out.println(signature);//
        String signatureBase64 = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(signature), CHARACTER_ENCODING);
        System.out.println(signatureBase64);
        return new String(signatureBase64);
    }

    private static String urlEncode(String rawValue) {
        String value = (rawValue == null) ? "" : rawValue;
        String encoded = null;

        try {
            encoded = URLEncoder.encode(value, CHARACTER_ENCODING)
                .replace("+", "%20")
                .replace("*", "%2A")
                .replace("%7E","~");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            System.err.println("Unknown encoding: " + CHARACTER_ENCODING);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return encoded;
    }
}
```

Right now we're testing this by hand because I'm trying to submit requests/manage the data through a Filemaker Database, so I may be adding the signature back to the URL query incorrectly. I'm assuming that 1) all of the parameters need to be listed in the query alphabetically and 2) the signature is the only exception that gets appended, last.

For example:

```
AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAITPQPJO62G4LAE7Q&Action=ListOrders&MarketplaceId.Id.1=XXXXXXXXXXX&Merchant=XXXXXXXXXXX&OrderStatus.Status.1=PartiallyShipped&OrderStatus.Status.2=Unshipped&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&SignatureVersion=2&Timestamp=2014-01-29T22%3A11%3A00Z&Version=2011-01-01&Signature=tNufJeONZlscTlHs%2FLAWBs7zwsfpIaQcUK%2B5XIPJpcQ%3D
```

But the response I keep getting is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ErrorResponse xmlns="https://mws.amazonservices.com/Orders/2011-01-01">
  <Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
    <Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.</Message>
  </Error>
  <RequestID>7532e668-c660-4db6-b129-f5fe5d3fad63</RequestID>
</ErrorResponse>
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Debugging is fun but I need to get past this already!